# Changing tag's properties of HTML file

Tags: html, angularjs, powershell

I am struggling with the regular expression in Powershell. I have to put `alt` property to each `img` tag in an `html` file. What I did is, I tried to find the `img` tag and replace the content of the tag with modified content by using regular expression. Here is my code:

```
$rowFile = Get-Content $file
$regex = ".+<img(.*?.+?)/>"
$regAlt = ".+ alt="
$newFile = ""
foreach($line in $rowFile){
    if($line -match $regex) { 
        if($line -notmatch $regAlt){
            $replaceValue = [string]$matches[1] + " alt=`"" + (Get-Random -input $altValues) + "`""
            $line = $line -replace [string]$matches[1], $replaceValue
        }
    }
    $newFile += [string]$line + "'n"
}
Set-Content -Path $file -Value $newFile
```

It works for general form of the tags like `<img src="../../Content/images/Delete_Row.png" class="size-20_20" />`. But, doesn't work for the tags having angular stuffs or we can say the braceses.

For example, `<img data-ng-src="{{vm.getDashBoardImagePath(menu.menuDescription)}}" />` and `<img class="size-20_20" src="../../Content/images/Edit_Row.png" data-ng-click="vm.editLabtest(test.labTestID)" />`.

Can anybody suggest me some solution to this problem?

Comment: Remove the "greedy" `.+`, it's not needed in the first place. Also `if($line -notmatch $regAlt)` should use `[string]$matches[1]` instead of `$line` to check only inside the tag.

Comment: Thanks wOxxOm for this lovely solution, Half of the problem has been solved by changing `$line` to `[string]$matches[1]`. But, wherever it finds parenthesis, it fails. For example,
`<img id="cart" src="~/Content/images/ShoppingBasket.png" data-ng-click="vm.showCartItem()" style="cursor: pointer;" />
 
to
 
<img id="cart" src="~/Content/images/ShoppingBasket.png" data-ng-click="vm.showCartItem()" style="cursor: pointer;" />`     Here no alt tag is added.

Comment: Same problem is with `<img class="img-responsive" src="@imageUrl" + (model.items.indexof(item) + 1))" />
 
to
 
<img class="img-responsive" src="@imageUrl" + (model.items.indexof(item) + 1))" />`

Comment: In the above example, it is showing run time exception. `InvalidOperation: ( class="img-res...f(item) + 1))`

Comment: I solved the problem by replacing two lines and the answer suggested by wOxxOm. `$replaceValue = " alt=`"" + (Get-Random -input $altValues) + "`"" + " />"
            $line = $line -replace "/>", $replaceValue`. And this solved my problem. Although, if any one have better solution, Please post. Thanks.